# changing repeats in a sequence

Tags: arrays, r

I have the following vector

```
328 328 328 328 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349
```

As you can see, 328 is repeated 4 times and 349 is repeated 12 times. I was wondering what's the most efficient way in R to renumber the 328 so that it is 328,329,330,331, and the 349's would be 349,350,351,...

I can do this using a for loop but I have a feeling R has a more "R-centric" approach.

Comment: Can you put that in a vector so that people can copy/paste into their R session directly?

Answer (score 4):

If this is the data

```
x = c(rep(328, 4), rep(349, 12))
```

You could make a run-length-encoding representation of it

```
r = rle(x)
```

then create sequences equal to the length of each run

```
s = lapply(r$lengths, seq_len)
```

and finally add these to the original data (minus 1, because the sequences created in the previous step start at 1)

```
unlist(Map("+", s, r$values - 1)
```

So

```
> r = rle(x)
> unlist(Map("+", lapply(r$lengths, seq_len), r$values - 1))
 [1] 328 329 330 331 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359 360
```

(@DWin's use of `seq` is cleaner, though). It would make sense to order the values of `x` first, if not already in order.

```
> (x = sample(x))
 [1] 349 349 349 349 349 349 328 349 349 328 328 328 349 349 349 349
> o = order(x)
> r = rle(x[o])
> unlist(Map(seq, r$values, length=r$length))[order(o)]
 [1] 349 350 351 352 353 354 328 355 356 329 330 331 357 358 359 360
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# Demonstrating efficient way to take comma-less sequence as input from console.

> x <- scan()
 1: 328 328 328 328 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349
29: 
Read 28 items

# Solution
unlist( mapply(seq, rle(x)$values, length=rle(x)$lengths ) )
# [1] 328 329 330 331 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357
# [26] 358 359 360
```

`rle` did seem like the obvious starting point but I didn't think of the `mapply` approach until I saw @MartinMorgan's `Map` solution

Answer (score 1):

if `vec` is your sequence with duplicates

```
Reduce(function(x,y) if (y %in% x) c(x, max(x) + 1) else c(x, y), vec[order(vec)])
```

Comment: Useful as a brain teaser. Adding a print() helps understand how the `%in%` condition works and taught me something very useful about Reduce. Thanks.